# Subtracting columns based on key column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes looking like

df1:

```
   ID    A   B   C   D 
0 'ID1' 0.5 2.1 3.5 6.6
1 'ID2' 1.2 5.5 4.3 2.2
2 'ID1' 0.7 1.2 5.6 6.0 
3 'ID3' 1.1 7.2 10. 3.2
```

df2:

```
   ID    A   B   C   D 
0 'ID1' 1.0 2.0 3.3 4.4
1 'ID2' 1.5 5.0 4.0 2.2
2 'ID3' 0.6 1.2 5.9 6.2 
3 'ID4' 1.1 7.2 8.5 3.0
```

df1 can have multiple entries with the same `ID` whereas each `ID` occurs only once in df2. Also not all `ID` in df2 are necessarily present in df1. I can't solve this by using `set_index()` as multiple rows in df1 can have the same `ID`, and that the `ID` in df1 and df2 are not aligned.

I want to create a new dataframe where I subtract the values in `df2[['A','B','C','D']]` from `df1[['A','B','C','D']]` based on matching the ID.

The resulting dataframe would look like:

df_new:

```
   ID     A    B   C   D 
0 'ID1' -0.5  0.1 0.2 2.2
1 'ID2' -0.3  0.5 0.3 0.0
2 'ID1' -0.3 -0.8 2.3 1.6
3 'ID3'  0.5  6.0 1.5 0.2
```

I know how to do this with a loop, but since I'm dealing with huge data quantities this is not practical at all. What is the best way of approaching this with Pandas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need set_index and subtract

```
(df1.set_index('ID')-df2.set_index('ID')).dropna(axis=0)
Out[174]: 
         A    B    C    D
ID                       
'ID1' -0.5  0.1  0.2  2.2
'ID1' -0.3 -0.8  2.3  1.6
'ID2' -0.3  0.5  0.3  0.0
'ID3'  0.5  6.0  4.1 -3.0
```

If the order matters add `reindex` for df2

```
(df1.set_index('ID')-df2.set_index('ID').reindex(df1.ID)).dropna(axis=0).reset_index()
Out[211]: 
      ID    A    B    C    D
0  'ID1' -0.5  0.1  0.2  2.2
1  'ID2' -0.3  0.5  0.3  0.0
2  'ID1' -0.3 -0.8  2.3  1.6
3  'ID3'  0.5  6.0  4.1 -3.0
```

Comment: The second solution was exactly what I needed, as the order does indeed matter for the usage of the resulting dataframe later in the process.

Comment: @AndersT ah:-) happy coding

Answer (score 8):

Similarly to what Wen (who beat me to it) proposed, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html):

```
df1.set_index('ID').subtract(df2.set_index('ID')).reset_index()

         A    B    C    D
ID                       
'ID1' -0.5  0.1  0.2  2.2
'ID1' -0.3 -0.8  2.3  1.6
'ID2' -0.3  0.5  0.3  0.0
'ID3'  0.5  6.0  4.1 -3.0
```

Comment: Note you do lose the order of the original dataframe. This may or may not be important.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `numpy`. We can extract the ordered indices required from `df2` using [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

Then feed this into the construction of a new dataframe.

```
idx = np.searchsorted(df2['ID'], df1['ID'])

res = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:, 1:].values - df2.iloc[:, 1:].values[idx],
                   index=df1['ID']).reset_index()

print(res)

      ID    0    1    2    3
0  'ID1' -0.5  0.1  0.2  2.2
1  'ID2' -0.3  0.5  0.3  0.0
2  'ID1' -0.3 -0.8  2.3  1.6
3  'ID3'  0.5  6.0  4.1 -3.0
```

Comment: I can understand why it was downvoted. It wasn't me by the way. Some might think it's not very pythonic compared to more simpler solutions. Run this: `import this`.