# Subtracting multiple columns between dataframes based on key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, example:

```
Df1 -

A   B   C   D
x   j   5   2
y   k   7   3
z   l   9   4
```

```
Df2 -

A   B   C   D
z   o   1   1
x   p   2   1
y   q   3   1
```

I want to deduct columns C and D in Df2 from columns C and D in Df1 based on the key contained in column A.

I also want to ensure that column B remains untouched, example:

```
Df3 -

A   B   C   D
x   j   3   1
y   k   4   2
z   l   8   3
```

I found an almost perfect answer in the following thread:
[Subtracting columns based on key column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158152/subtracting-columns-based-on-key-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

However what the answer does not explain is if there are other columns in the primary df (such as column B) that should not be involved as an index or with the operation.

Is somebody please able to advise?

I was originally performing a loop which find the value in the other df and deducts it however this takes too long for my code to run with the size of data I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is specify column(s) for maching and column(s) for subtract, convert all not `cols` columnsnames to `MultiIndex`, subtract:

```
match = ['A']
cols = ['C','D']
df1 = Df1.set_index(match + Df1.columns.difference(match + cols).tolist())

df = df1.sub(Df2.set_index(match)[cols], level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  x  j  3  1
1  y  k  4  2
2  z  l  8  3
```

Or replace not matched values to original `Df1`:

```
match = ['A']
cols = ['C','D']
df1 = Df1.set_index(match)

df = df1.sub(Df2.set_index(match)[cols], level=0).reset_index().fillna(Df1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  x  j  3  1
1  y  k  4  2
2  z  l  8  3
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer. It's a little difficult to apply because the above is an example and there are actually 6 - 8 columns that column B represents... is there a method that doesn't involve explicitly setting every column as an index first?

Comment: @SlowlyLearning - Is possible specify columns for subtract?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: @SlowlyLearning - Answer was edited.